# how can I create an E-commerce CART system using python Django

Tags: python, django

I am developing an E-commerce website and encountering difficulties in implementing a cart system. please,   Can anyone guide me through the process of implementing a cart system or provide some helpful resources? Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: What sort of guidance do you need? On the database design? What kind of APIs you need? Is it for REST APIs or for standard Django application? I am afraid, your question is too general.

Comment: the database design actually